# Understanding cryptic latex errors: font shape undefined

Tags: fonts, xetex, latin-modern

I have a couple of errors in my log about `LatinModernMath` fonts.

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/LatinModernMath(1)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/LatinModernMath(1)/m/n' instead on input line 225

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/LatinModernMath(2)/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/LatinModernMath(2)/m/n' instead on input line 225
```

How do I find out which file those lines belong to? It's a really big document with lots of math split in several files (merged with `\include`), I'd like to check if the shape it's falling back to is ok, but I have no idea what to look for.

I'm using `xelatex` with `unicode-math`, main font *Minion*, math font *Latin Modern Math*.

Comment: Using Latin Modern for math and Minion for text is a capital sin; they're visually incompatible. Anyhow, the question cannot be answered in its current form.

Comment: those are warnings not errors. you could choose to ignore them, as long as your document is typeset (almost) properly, or go on to a deep level debug.

Comment: @naphaneal sure I could ignore them more easily if I had any idea about which shape it's referring to, or even which file.

Comment: it is telling you that there is no bold latin modern math and so it's using the normal weight one instead, note that math fonts need to be set up in advance so you will get this warning even if you do not use any bold in math unless you explicitly disable setting up of bold math

Comment: @DavidCarlisle weird, all the bold symbols I'm using (with `\symbf`) look fine to me. Guess I'll ignore it...

Comment: `\symbf` does not require a bold font (that's the main reason a new command was introduced instead of `\mathbf` which does require a bold font)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is telling you that there is no bold latin modern math and so it's using the normal weight one instead. Note that math fonts need to be set up in advance so you will get this warning even if you do not use any bold fonts in math unless you explicitly disable setting up of bold math

Bold symbols accessed via `\symbf` does not require a bold font, it instead takes the bold characters from the bold mathematical characters in the Unicode mathematical characters block. That's the main reason a new command was introduced instead of `\mathbf` which does require a bold font. `\symbf` changes the character number of the character to be accessed rather than changing the font. So the warning does not affect `\symbf` but would for example mean that `\boldmath` (or the AMS `\boldsymbol`) will produce normal weight not bold.

Comment: thank you, `\symbf` was actually the very reason why I started using `unicode-math` as I couldn't get a couple of symbols (mostly `\theta`) to be bold with neither of `\mathbf`, `\boldsymbol`, `\bm`...